# Is it possible to convert a variable to a factor after you have done multiple imputation using "mice"?

Tags: r, r-mice

is it possible to convert a variable into a factor after having used MICE? For example:

```
library(mice)
imp <- mice(nhanes)
```

Say I realized that I needed nhanes$hyp as a factor variable. I know that I can extract the 5 imputed datasets and convert this variable into a factor in all of them:

```
c1 <- complete(imp, 1)
c2 <- complete(imp, 2)
c3 <- complete(imp, 3)
c4 <- complete(imp, 4)
c5 <- complete(imp, 5)
c1$hyp <- as.factor(c1$hyp)
```

and so on.

But how to get these new versions stored within `imp` to be used in analysis? thank you!

Comment: What analysis do you want to do specifically? It seems like you should just be able to do the casting when you do the modeling.

Comment: @MrFlick I didn't know that, thank you!!